# Picking randomly one card till we get the first heart

Tags: probability

From a standard pack of cards $(\spadesuit, \heartsuit, \diamondsuit, \clubsuit)$ we are picking randomly one card in a each time (with replacement) until we get the first heart $\heartsuit$.

$(A.)$ Find the probability that there will be **exactly** $5$ cards picked.

$(B.)$ Find the probability that there will be **more** then $5$ cards picked.

---

**My attempt:**

$(A.)$

Let $X$ be a random variable $X\sim G(\frac{13}{52}=1/4)$

So $P[X=5]=(1-1/4)^{4}\cdot\frac 1 4=\frac{81}{1024}$

$(B.)$

$$P[Y=1]=(1-1/4)^0\cdot\frac 1 4=\frac{3}{16}\\
P[Y=2]=(1-1/4)^1\cdot\frac 1 4=\frac{3}{16}\\
P[Y=3]=(1-1/4)^2\cdot\frac 1 4=\frac{9}{64}\\
P[Y=4]=(1-1/4)^3\cdot\frac 1 4=\frac{27}{256}\\
P[Y=5]=\frac{81}{1024}$$

$$P[Y>5]=1-\underbrace{\bigg(P[Y=1]+\dots+P[Y=5]\bigg)}_{=(307)/(1024)}\\
\Longrightarrow 1-\frac{307}{1024}=\frac{717}{1024}$$

Is my attempt correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For B), we want the probability of five non-hearts in a row. This is $(3/4)^5$.

Your way of attacking the problem is also correct, it is a bit more work. Note that $\Pr(Y=1)$ was not computed correctly, it should be $1/4$.